# Append string to some rows

Tags: r, string, string-concatenation, sqldf

In my dataframe, one of my columns (of class `character`) has entries who are either 5 or 9 characters long. I want to take those who are 5 characters long, and append 4 zeros behind to make them 9 characters long. (EG turn `12345` in `123450000`)

I tried to do it using `sqldf` and the following code :

```
mydf<-sqldf("UPDATE mydf SET column = column + '0000' WHERE LENGTH(column) < 6")
```

but for some reason, it turns `mydf` into a `null` value, I think the problem is with the concatenation.

Also tried `concat()`, but I get:

> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
>     error in statement: no such function: concat`.

**NB**: answer doesn't necessarily have to use sqldf, I was just giving one way I tried to do it.

Comment: Please add proper tag to question so every one can understand

Comment: may be `mydf$column=ifelse(nchar(mydf$column)<6,paste0(mydf$column,'0000'),mydf$column)`

Comment: Works, thank you very much ! (You can put it in answer if you want, I'll accept it). By the way, if anyone knows why my attempt with sqldf did not work, I'm curious :)

Comment: You can also use the `stringr` package for a "cleaner" solution. `str_pad(mydf$column, 9, side = "right")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try simply `ifelse`

`mydf$column=ifelse(nchar(mydf$column)<6,paste0(mydf$column,'0000'),mydf$column)‌​`

Answer (score 3):

*sqldf* does not update R objects, we need to return the result from *sql environment* after update, see below example:

```
library(sqldf)

#dummy data
mydf <- data.frame(column=c("1","100","12345","1234567"))

#update and return the result
mydf1 <- sqldf(c("UPDATE mydf
                  SET column = column || '0000'
                  WHERE LENGTH(column) < 6",
                 "SELECT *
                  FROM main.mydf"))
#output
mydf1
#      column
# 1     10000
# 2   1000000
# 3 123450000
# 4   1234567
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than update use select statement.

```
sqldf("select *, column||'0000' from mydf where length(column)<6")
```